# Event to handle google map rectangle resize

Tags: events, google-maps-api-3, size, rectangles

I want to get an event to handle when an rectangle object change its size.

I tried **bounds_changed** as follow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, "bounds_changed", function() {
    Foo();
});
```

It works, the problem with bounds_changed is that it is called a lot of time before the user ends to resize the rectangle, so my function 'Foo' runs in any step making my page SLOW.

Is there an event like that I'm looking for? some approach to get it?

Thanks in advance.